# How to split pages in a pdf?

Tags: pdf

I would like to cut a pdf file so that every "slide" is on a new page.
Original document layout looks like this:
[image: pdf structure]

Comment: What OS are you using? What program are you using to generate the PDF?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I didn't generate the PDF. The slides may contain text or images. Windows and linux solutions are both ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sejda PDF can help you split PDF pages down the middle.

https://www.sejda.com/split-pdf-down-the-middle

Once you have the document where each slide is on a separate page you can crop them to remove unnecessary margins:

https://www.sejda.com/crop-pdf

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this can be done per slide, but If all the pages contain 2 slides, splitting pages in half may work for you.

http://www.a-pdf.com/faq/how-to-cut-the-pdf-pages-in-half-so-each-would-have-its-own-page-within-the-page.htm

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the "slides" on the pages are imported images. Depending on which method was used to create the pdf, a software might help you to extract the images. You could then print the images one-per-page as pdf.

In Linux, this could be `pdfimages` from the `poppler-utils` package or `imagemagick`'s `pdfimages`.

On Windows, you could either screenshot the images, or, as an example, install `imagemagick` and also use `pdfimages`.

Edit: if all that still does not output images (e. g. because the slides are all Powerpoint shapes), I'd try to use a screenshot tool which helps me to automate the process. `Picpick` (for Windows), for example, can be set to screenshot the same area across multiple captures. So I'd set this up for the first slide, scroll to the next and hit PicPick's short key for screen capture.

Another alternative which comes to my mind for a scenario, where the slides are Powerpoint shapes is an image editor which can open pdfs, e. g. `Irfanview` with the pdf plugin. Open the pdf in that image editor and save it as a series of images. I'd go with bmp, png or tiff if the quality of the later images is important. After that, you have a series of images with two slides on each of them. Run `imagemagick` on them to extract the single images.

Comment: I used this method, however I cannot recall whether it was a pdf created by a current Powerpoint. That brings me to another idea I will add in my answer, though.